# How to read and update table row by row sql and php?

Tags: php, sql

I have a database where I want to read a table row by row and then for each row I want to update a cell. I have written the below code but is there a better way of doing this ? Better way I mean it takes less time than my code.
Here is my code :

```
$List = 'some text...';
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM TABLE";
$res = mysqli_query($database, $SQL);


    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        if(strpos($List,$row['name']) !== false){
            mysqli_query($database, "UPDATE TABLE SET `yes`=1 WHERE name='".$row['name']."'");
        }else{
            mysqli_query($database, "UPDATE TA SET `yes`=0 WHERE name='".$row['name']."'");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you use LOCATE in the query, something like "update table set 'yes' = if( locate(name, $list)=0, 0, 1)".

Comment: Does it update all the rows ? @droopsnoot

Comment: @zizo123456 before you do anything else at all you need to start learning about prepared statements.  If the resource you are using to learn from is telling you to put data directly from a variable into an SQL query you need to bin it.  Personally I prefer PDO, but if you like mysqli then maybe this is a good place to start: https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: @jameson2012 Thank u... It's just a test and I use prepared statements. For asking my question I prefer using `mysqli_query` and directly put my data :)

Comment: @zizo123456 "it's just a test" is the kind of philosophy that ends with people accidentally leaving insecure code in production.  Even if it's a test you should treat it as production code.  And as for preferring it for your question here, I suspect you'll spend a lot of time being told your code is outdated and insecure.

Comment: @jameson2012 Ok... I'm convinced ;) I will use prepared statements even in my questions from now on in case other people may not still know about it or as u say "people accidentally leaving insecure code in production".

Comment: it will make your time here much more pleasant, believe me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That approach is not the best one, the idea of SQL is to manage and be able to do that in a more efficient way. Instead of iterating each row and executing total rows +1 queries you can do only 2 queries and update the information.

for Example:

```
-- Update all to 0
UPDATE TABLE SET `yes`=0 ;

-- Update the one on the list to 1
UPDATE TABLE SET `yes`=1 WHERE name in ('value1','value2','value3');
```

This approach could save you a lot of execution time and be more efficient event on very large datasets.

Comment: Thanks for ur response. Just don't know `WHERE name in ('place1','place2','place3');` functionality actually and what should I put instead of  `place1`, `place2`, and so on...

Comment: you have a list **$list="some info";** what is the contents of that list ? instead of having a string with the values you can have an array and use it to construct the query. like the example **'place1','place2'** and son on.

Comment: what if I just use my string and not converting it into an array ? No way ?

Comment: How you are breaking the different values on the $list variable ?

Comment: I'm not breaking... I'm just using `strpos` as u see in my code

Comment: you are indirectly breaking it by space.. If you have a row with the value Johnathan and in the list you have John, you are going to have a true on strpos and the query is going to be executed and will not have a match an no update will be done. That's why I use arrays because I want to have a exact match.

Comment: Then here's the best answer for u... Didn't think about that. :)

Answer (score 0):

i have 2 solution here

Solution 1 :

Copy the table and perform the update and rename the orginal table and also rename copy 1 table to original 1

table_1 copy to table_2
perform the operation on table_2

then rename table_1 to bkp_table_1
then rename table_2 to table_1

Solution 2

with the user select insert the data in new table which you what to update.

Comment: None of them are standard solutions indeed... What we talk about in stackoverflow is standard programming.